# Connecting two DialogBoxes in GWT

Tags: api, gwt, google-maps, dialog

In my GWT project, I'm trying to get it so two DialogBoxes can pass information between each other.  One of them holds a MapWidget, and when a button is pressed in the other DialogBox, the position information is received from that other DialogBox's MapWidget.  Does anyone have any tips for how I should coordinate between having two different DialogBoxes show up?  Should I wrap the code for the two in a Composite?  Furthermore, is there an example anywhere of dealing with two DialogBoxes at once in GWT?  For example, if I click outside of the two boxes, both should be dismissed.  I'm wondering if there's a way to keep both of them in focus at once, so I can switch between the two without causing either to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sharing Data Between Dialog Boxes**

In my opinion, the "correct" way to do this would be to implement some sort of [MVP structure](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/mvp-architecture.html) in the application so that a presenter manages the view (`DialogBox`es, among other things) and knows how to pass simple data to the view for it to display (the presenter would handle the `MapWidget` data, the view would take care of displaying it on the DOM).

However, if you're looking for a quicker/more simpler approach, you have a couple of options (which you choose really depends on the application structure):

1. Create a `Composite`, as you mentioned, that knows how to pass the necessary data back and forth. By having the `Composite` manage the data object and tell the two `DialogBox`es how to display it, you are actually approaching an MVP architecture within your `Composite`.
2. Subclass `DialogBox` into a class that contains a `HandlerManager` (sometimes used as an "Event Bus") that fires events when the button is pressed. You can create events that are designed to pass data back and forth between the two `DialogBox`es (even make them type-safe with type parameters). See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998621/gwt-custom-event-handler) for details on using a `HandlerManager`. The MVP article, linked above, also has some [good information on using an event bus](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/mvp-architecture.html#events).

Model-View-Presenter is a tried-and-true method of structuring an application that results in more testable code, better project structure, and can help guide you when making decisions like this. I strongly recommend checking it out if you haven't already.

**Sharing Auto-Hide Functionality**

GWT's `PopupPanel` (on which `DialogBox` is based) offers a method [`addAutoHidePartner(Element)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html#addAutoHidePartner(com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element)) which is describe thusly:

> Mouse events that occur within an autoHide partner will not hide a panel set to autoHide.

So, you can create two auto-hiding `DialogBox`es that only close when you click outside both of them (e.g., they do not close when you click within either of the boxes) with the following code:

```
// Create the dialog boxes
DialogBox dbox1 = new DialogBox(true, false);
DialogBox dbox2 = new DialogBox(true, false);
// Set some visual options
dbox1.setPopupPosition(10, 10);
dbox2.setPopupPosition(200, 10);
dbox1.setAnimationEnabled(true);
dbox2.setAnimationEnabled(false);
// Set the dialog boxes' caption and content
dbox1.setHTML("Dialog Box 1");
dbox2.setHTML("Dialog Box 2");
dbox1.setWidget(new HTML("This is the first dialog box."));
dbox2.setWidget(new HTML("This is the second dialog box."));
// Making dobx2 a partner of dbox1 means clicking
// in dbox2 won't cause dbox1 to close
dbox1.addAutoHidePartner(dbox2.getElement());
// Similarly, setting dbox1 as a partner of dbox2 means
// clicking in dbox1 won't cause dbox2 to close
dbox2.addAutoHidePartner(dbox1.getElement());
// Show the dialog boxes
dbox1.show();
dbox2.show();
```

You can interact with either of the dialog boxes without the other closing. Omit the appropriate call to `setAutoHidePartner` if you only want a one-way partnership.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works!  The only issue is that it seems like I can't have setGlassEnabled(true) for both of the DialogBox'es.  Oh well.

Comment: Glad to hear it! You may consider overloading `show()` to check to see if the other `DialogBox` is shown yet and has glass enabled, and thus programmatically set the glass's enabled state before calling the parent `show()`. This would allow you to have glass enabled any time either one or both `DialogBox`es are showing. (You would also have to check the glass state when the boxes are dismissed, of course.)