# SmartGwt custom events

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

Is it possible to use custom events with smartgwt? I use the tutorial from [GWT Custom Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951621/gwt-custom-events) but not only it does not work in smartgwt but the existing handlers are not working also. Is there a specific way to implement custom events in smartgwt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that is not possible directly in SmartGWT. We had a need for custom events too, but having searched for solution for a couple of days we found out it is not possible and had to come up with a different design.