# Custom ValueChangeHandler GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I need to write a custom `ValueChangeHandler` and call out `onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent)`. However I don't understand how to write a `ValueChangeEvent`.

Maybe I understand the entire GWT event system wrong. Can anyone help?

**Edit:** I am asking how to create my own class that dispatches the ValueChangeEvent. I understand how to listen to it.

The constructor of ValueChangeEvent is not visible and I can't create it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to fire a `ValueChangeEvent` you must implement the interface `HasValueChangeHandlers` by or your class or somewhere in the class.

A simple implementation would be to use the EventBus:

```
EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus();

@Override
public void fireEvent(GwtEvent<?> event) {
    bus.fireEvent(event);
}

@Override
public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<T> handler) {
    return bus.addHandler(ValueChangeEvent.getType(), handler);
}
```

Note you need to substitute `T` with the type you want to fire.

Because you can't create a ValueChangeEvent directly dispatching an event is done via the fire method:

```
ValueChangeEvent.fire(this, value);
```

Where `this` refers to the class/field implementing the `HasValueChangeHandlers` and `value` refers to the value that has been changed and you want to dispatch the event.

Comment: Thanks, I got everything else to work by now but I didn't know abut the EventBut.

Comment: @Hilibrand - Hey, I need to do this exact thing again in GWT 2.0.4 that doesn't have EventBus. I cannot find any reference for it. Do you know how its done?

Comment: For GWT 2.0.4 you can use the `com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager` class. You can initialize it with the current class: `new HandlerManager(this);`

Answer (score 12):

Actually, instead of creating a new EventBus or HandlerManager, as your widget will be a subclass of Wiget, it the standard way would be to use the Widget.addHandler(handler, eventType) method. Here's a minimal example:

```
    public class MyWidget<T> extends Composite implements HasValueChangeHandlers<T>, HasValue<T> {

    private T value;

    public MyWidget() {
        // Initialize stuff
    }

    @Override
    public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(final ValueChangeHandler<T> handler) {
        return addHandler(handler, ValueChangeEvent.getType());
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
        setValue(value, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value, boolean fireEvents) {
        this.value = value;
        if (fireEvents) {
            ValueChangeEvent.fire(this, getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The class only needs to implement the HasValue<T> interface.

Answer (score 1):

Really late to answer, but I've just solved this problem like this:

```
ValueChangeEvent.fire(hasValueChangeHandlerInstance, getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueChangeEvent` is generated for you by GWT. You can add one (or more) `ValueChangeHandler` to any class that implements the interface `HasValueChangeHandlers`. One of these classes is `TextArea`, so let's look at a little example:

```
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    textArea.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

When the value of the text area changes, GWT will automatically generate a ValueChangeEvent, which you can use in the part I marked with "do something".

Comment: I don't need that. I am creating my own "TextArea" and I need that to dispatch a ValueChangeEvent just like TextArea does.

Comment: Ok, your question suggested you wanted to know how to write a ValueChangeHandler (as opposed to a HasValueChangeHandlers implementation) :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry for the misleading question. English is not my native tongue :(.