# passing parameters from one presenter to another with GWT-Platform

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I'm trying to pass a parameter that I have loaded on a presenter to another presenter, a car from some client, for example.

What's the best way to do this? Using the gatekeeper? Any example?

PS: I using DI with gin and the GWT-Platform framework.

Comment: If the state for the 2nd presenter should be bookmarkable you can use `prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest)` to handle parameters. In your 1st presenter you use `PlaceManager.revealPlace(PlaceRequest)` with a newly generated `PlaceRequest` containing the parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the presenter should be loaded when the event is fired you can use a `ProxyEvent`. Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted?tm=6#Attaching_events_to_proxies and http://arcbees.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/using-proxyevent/.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reduce coupling, you should create a custom event, `CarLoadedEvent` or something. Use GWTP Plugin for that, it works great.
Then have your presenter that wants to catch that event implement `CarLoadedHandler`, and in its `onBind()` method, make it register to the eventBus :

> @Override
>   protected void onBind() {
>   super.onBind();
>   registerHandler(getEventBus().addHandler(CarLoadedEvent.TYPE, this));
>   }

Finally, when a car is loaded, fire an event :

> CarLoadedEvent.fire(getEventBus(), myLoadedCar);

Comment: Agreed w/ Mikael. I have several examples in my code at https://github.com/dartmanx/mapmaker/tree/0.5.2 in the client package. I used GWT-Platform as well.

Comment: and how i do it if my other presenter is not visible yet?

Comment: Haha, I didn't see it that way ! In the case the next presenter hasn't been instantiated yet, I'd just pass the ID of the car as a URL parameter (see comment of your question by z00bs), and the request the car to the server.

Comment: haha, yea, I've not explain right my question, i just don't want to load it multiple times.. do you have another suggestion?

Comment: I decide to pass the id by PlaceRequest and it worked, and, thinking about other things, like maintain the object updated, i will use this way. Well, like no one else said anything, I will vote for the only answer. Thank you mikael-couzic.

Answer (score 0):

See GWTP doc & blog:

- [for regular Event handling](http://blog.arcbees.com/2015/04/01/gwt-platform-event-best-practices-revisited/)
- [for Event handling that should wake up another Presenter not yet initialized/showing](https://arcbees.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/using-proxyevent/)
- [boilerplate code generation related to simplifying coding Event handling](http://dev.arcbees.com/gwtp/tools/Boilerplate-Generation.html)