# GWT: How to know if my listbox selected index changed

Tags: gwt

I have a listbox ,which have two values   value1  and  value 2 ..

Now my listbox values got change programatically (I dont change the values Manually)

I want to get a prompt prompt whenever a value get changes / index get changed, inside my listbox

```
             ListBox listBox = new LisBox();
```

if i use

```
             listBox.addClickHandler
```

or

```
             listBox.addChangeListener
```

or
                 listBox.addChangeEvent

They all only shows me a prompt when i manually change my listbox selected Index.But how will i get a prompt when my listbox selectedIndex changed programatically

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using

```
setSelectedIndex
```

The [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29) says explicitly states that it will not send an event. You could overwrite setSelectedIndex and send your own event. A good explaination of doing so can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951621/gwt-custom-events).