# How to destroy a GWT Bootstrap Modal when it is closed

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I have some data that is displayed in a CellTable, one of the columns is a clickable. On clicking that column I display the data associated with it in another CellTable inside of a [Modal](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/Modal.html).

I have set up a UIBinder element for this.

In the FieldUpdater I create a new instance of the UIBinder element, after it is closed I want it to be destroyed or removed from the `DOM`. This element has a [GWT Bootstrap Moda](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/gwt-bootstrap/apidocs/com/github/gwtbootstrap/client/ui/Modal.html)l

What happens now is that it gets hidden and when I click the new instance is created. I think this will be a problem when the size of the data increases and on prolonged use of the application.

I'd like to know how I can either reopen the existing element or destroy the element once it is closed. I couldn't find any event like `onClose`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't "setDynamicSafe" do exactly what you want?

> Setup the modal to prevent memory leaks. When modal is hidden, will remove all event Handlers, and them remove the modal DOM from document DOM. Default is false.
>
> Parameters: dynamicSafe

Answer (score 0):

You can override the hide() method.

if you want to send a onClose event, create a [custom event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951621/gwt-custom-events).