# GWT make RPC blocking

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

Is it possible to make a gwt rpc blocking? i.e. the application blocks until a response is received from the server

Comment: You might want to add a bit more info. Blocking calls in a javascript application (which is what GWT ultimately boils down to) are almost never a good idea. You need to have really good reasons to do this, and most things can be solved using asynchronous calls (e.g. set a flag and don't execute certain things if it's set).

Comment: I have an application which it can completly load if the user details are obtained from the server, so when the app starts, I make an RPC and then the result from the rpc are use to feed in the app, I cannot continue until the data from the rpc is obtained so I want to make the rpc blocking so that only when the rpc completes, then the application can start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no gwt rpc blocking because it is opposite idea to the asynchronous callback.

But you can use these two methods

1. Timer. Count timer and check that there is any return object that is not null and stop and cancel timer and continue your job. If timer is active don't do other job. This is very very inefficient way. **Lack of OO design pattern and too many if-else-if statements**
2. Call Rpc and do all actions in `onSuccess()` method. It guarantees that your method is finished and successfully finished then continue to other methods.

My advise is 2nd one (onSuccess). I want to mention again that blocking is never a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Well, synchronus rpc calls are called as evils by GWT designers. They do have very strong arguments... But you can succeed synchronous rpc by means of hacks..Here is one of them,
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4898

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution that came to my mind would be to "block" your application from the point where the Asynchronous call starts till the filling is completed, which would be at the end of the `onSuccess()` method.

By blocking I mean just to show some [animated loading gif](http://www.aksharassociate.com/images/icon-loading-animated.gif) in the middle of the page.